# Tooltipster not working on mobile devices - Wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, tooltipster

Tooltipster jquery plugin is loaded to trigger tooltips "on hover" state.

When on a mobile device, the "hover" trigger does not load - I would therefore like to change the trigger to "click" when on mobile devices.

I have tried the following edit in tooltipster.core.js:
but this just disables the tooltips, and does not change the "trigger" to click
...trigger: 'click', changed from trigger: 'hover',

```
var defaults = {
        animation: 'fade',
        animationDuration: 350,
        content: null,
        contentAsHTML: false,
        contentCloning: false,
        debug: true,
        delay: 300,
        delayTouch: [300, 500],
        functionInit: null,
        functionBefore: null,
        functionReady: null,
        functionAfter: null,
        functionFormat: null,
        IEmin: 6,
        interactive: false,
        multiple: false,
        // must be 'body' for now, or an element positioned at (0, 0)
        // in the document, typically like the very top views of an app.
        parent: 'body',
        plugins: ['sideTip'],
        repositionOnScroll: false,
        restoration: 'none',
        selfDestruction: true,
        theme: [],
        timer: 0,
        trackerInterval: 500,
        trackOrigin: false,
        trackTooltip: false,
        trigger: 'click',
        triggerClose: {
            click: false,
            mouseleave: false,
            originClick: false,
            scroll: false,
            tap: false,
            touchleave: false
        },
        triggerOpen: {
            click: false,
            mouseenter: false,
            tap: false,
            touchstart: false
        },
        updateAnimation: 'rotate',
        zIndex: 9999999
    },
```

Answer (score 7):

## BIG EDIT

*(check history if you wish, I left only what is relevant for a working solution)*

**Okay, so first of**, if you modified any of the ToolTipster plugin files, just undo all your changes or download and re-install fresh files.

That said, when I talked about *"init"* in the comments, I was talking about the script which instantiate the ToolTipster function... In your web page content.

As per ToolTipster's documentation, [Instantiating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instance_(computer_science)) the ToolTipster plugin to do what you want (open/close the tooltips on click/tap, not hover) is done this way, somewhere between the `<body>` and `</body>` tags:

`trigger:"custom",` is needed to use `triggerOpen` and `triggerClose` parameters.
It, in fact, just set all built-in trigger event listeners to false and enables the custom triggers to be set.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.tooltip').tooltipster({
    animation: 'fade',
    delay: 200,
    theme: 'tooltipster-punk',
    trigger:"custom",
    triggerOpen: {
      click: true,  // For mouse
      tap: true    // For touch device
    },
    triggerClose: {
      click: true,  // For mouse
      tap: true    // For touch device
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

### Now to use it on a link

*(This is optional work I've done through my attempts)*

Since a link opens an `href` by default, may be you will want it not to...
And have the `dblclick` event instead to open a link.
*(You will have to mention your users about this "unusual" double-click thing)*
;)

I've done it all in the below snippet.
**NOTE that SO is preventing tabs to open** in the snippet sandbox...
[**It is working great in CodePen**](http://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/VpamZq)

```js
$('#myPageTitle').tooltipster({
  animation: 'fade',
  delay: 200,
  theme: 'tooltipster-punk',
  trigger:'custom',
  content: "Welcome to my new website.",
  triggerOpen: {
    click: true,  // For mouse
    tap: true    // For touch device
  },
  triggerClose: {
    click: true,  // For mouse
    tap: true    // For touch device
    }
});

$('.coolLink').tooltipster({
  animation: 'fade',
  delay: 200,
  theme: 'tooltipster-punk',
  trigger:"custom",
  content: "This is a cool link to visit! Double-click! (not working on SO)",
  triggerOpen: {
    click: true,  // For mouse
    tap: true    // For touch device
  },
  triggerClose: {
    click: true,  // For mouse
    tap: true    // For touch device
  }
});

$('#eoi').tooltipster({
  animation: 'fade',
  delay: 200,
  theme: 'tooltipster-punk',
  trigger:"custom",
  content: "This is the End of Internet.",
  triggerOpen: {
    click: true,  // For mouse
    tap: true    // For touch device
  },
  triggerClose: {
    click: true,  // For mouse
    tap: true    // For touch device
  }
});

// Those are handler for links, since a click open an href automatically
// You can set the href open on double click (dblclick event) instead.
//
// NOTE that StackOverFlow prevents a window open in the snippet sandbox...
//      But it works. ;)
$("a.coolLink, a#eoi").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
});
$("a.coolLink, a#eoi").on("dblclick",function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  window.open($(this).attr("href"));
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.tooltipster/4.2.2/css/tooltipster.bundle.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.tooltipster/4.2.2/js/tooltipster.bundle.min.js"></script>

<div style="text-align:center;">
<h1 id="myPageTitle">My Page Title</h1>
<br>
<br>
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com" target="_blank" class="coolLink">StackOverflow</a><br>
<br>
<a href="http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/#options" target="_blank" class="coolLink">ToolTipster options</a><br>
<br>
<br>
<a href="http://endoftheinternet.com/" target="_blank" id="eoi">End of Internet</a><br>
</div>
```

Be sure to include the jQuery library, the ToolTipster **bundle** libraries.
You can find it all [here](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/tooltipster). or [here](http://www.jsdelivr.com/projects/jquery.tooltipster)

Comment: thank you. and is this the correct file to edit this in ("tooltipster.core.js")

Comment: Never edit the files of a library. This is configuration only to put in your own code, read the documentation.

Comment: You have to pass these params on init of the function. Here is the documentation you should read : http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/#options

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Thank you. I have read the docs. and cannot find the file which contains the init of the function. Only the library files. I have taken this project over from someone, and am unsure of their practices. Please can you advise in more detail as to where I can find the init of the function

Comment: I think I ran through the same problem as you... I was quite more difficult than it looked, since *I think* I've found a documentation glitch... Have a look.

Comment: Please open an issue at Tooltipster if you think found a glitch. I'm not sure why "Now... This just don't work" because it works for me in this fiddle in Chrome at least: https://jsfiddle.net/5xqqmrt6/43/. And rather than checking opacity of the HTML, use the `status` method, it will give you the state of the tooltip.

Comment: mmm... You just got me mystified! The only thing I see is that I'm using different CDNs (not the "bundle" files). Thank you! I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this for the `trigger` value when initializing tooltipster:

```
trigger: ('ontouchstart' in window) ? 'click' : 'hover'
```